# How to install phpmyadmin in centOS

Tags: centos, nginx, centos6, phpmyadmin

I use a vps and it has centOS 6.5 .
I installed Nginx and php and mySql clearly. But when I tried to install phpMyAdmin by [these steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-a-centos-6-4-vps) , in Step Three when I enter this code:

`sudo yum install phpmyadmin`

It returns this error during runing:

`Error: php56w-common conflicts with php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

So what should I do for this problem?

Note that I did [these steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-6) to Install Linux, nginx, MySQL, PHP (LEMP) stack on CentOS 6.

Comment: You could just download phpmyadmin and extract it to your web directory (/var/www/html).

Answer (score 2):

Apperently you also configured the [Webtatic](https://webtatic.com/packages/php56/) yum repository to get a newer version of PHP (php56w) than what is included by default in CentOS or provided by EPEL. That conflicts with the PHP version the EPEL phpMyAdmin package expects.

It could well be that phpMyAdmin still works well with a (much) newer PHP version and then the suggested `--skip-broken` is a solution. An alternative would be to remove the webtatic PHP packages and downgrade to the CentOS/EPEL PHP versions instead.

Comment: Just like HBruijn said, 

Alternatively, you can download latest version of phpMyAdmin from there: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php